# Group of ungrouped column chart

Tags: highcharts

how can we plot group of overlapping column bars like the image shown. That is not a stacked and grouping chart because within the each group, each item is overlapped but not stacked.(both start from common zero).

http://s22.postimg.org/wun8gxh29/highcharts.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you disable the [column grouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.grouping):

```
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            grouping: false
        }
    },
```

You can explicitly control the placement of each column.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dd2fV/1/).